# Swift 4: Firebase still creating user even on error?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, swift4

I have a function that runs when the register button is pressed, which uses  `Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password)` to register the user if they don't already have an account, or there are no errors. Then I add them in the database and sign them in. If there are any errors, I display the error and `return`.

However, even if the user has never registered before and the database does not have their info, I'm getting the `.emailAlreadyInUse` error, after which the user is added to the database anyway. Firebase seems to be creating the account and then giving me an error. Why is this and how can I fix it?

Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func registerPressed(_ sender: Any?) {

        //set up new user using Firebase
        if (firstNameTextField.text! == "" && emailTextField.text! == "" && passwordTextField.text! == "") {
            self.topMessage.text = "Please enter your details"
        } else if (firstNameTextField.text! == "" && emailTextField.text! != "" && passwordTextField.text! != "") {
            self.topMessage.text = "Please enter your first name"
        } else {
            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!) {
                (user, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!)
                    if let errCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: error!._code) {
                        switch errCode {
                        case .weakPassword:
                            self.topMessage.text = "Password too short"
                            break
                        case .emailAlreadyInUse:
                            self.topMessage.text = "Email already in use"
                            break
                        case .invalidEmail:
                            self.topMessage.text = "Invalid email"
                            break
                        case .missingEmail:
                            self.topMessage.text = "Please enter an email"
                            break
                        default:
                            self.topMessage.text = "Error :( Please try again!"
                            break
                        }
                    }
                    return
                }
                else if let user = user {

                    let username = self.firstNameTextField.text!
                    let name = self.firstNameTextField.text!
                    let email = self.emailTextField.text!
                    let profileImage = ""
                    let password = self.passwordTextField.text!

                    let newUser = User(uid: user.uid, username: username, name: name, profileImage: profileImage, email: email, userCoins: 0, questsComplete: 0, rewardsRedeemed: 0, streak: 0, isSubscribed: false)

                    newUser.save(completion: { (error) in
                        if error != nil {
                            print(error!)
                        } else {
                            //successfully initialised
                            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
                                if let error = error {
                                    print(error)
                                } else {
                                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "registerToMainMap", sender: self)
                                }
                            })

                        }
                    })

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation [Firebase documentation on errors](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/errors)

> **FIRAuthErrorCodeEmailAlreadyInUse** Indicates the email used to attempt sign up already exists. Call **fetchProvidersForEmail** to check which sign-in mechanisms such user used, and prompt the user to sign in with one of those.

So, what does something like this give you?

```
Auth.auth().fetchProviders(forEmail: emailTextField.text!) { (email,completion) in
   print("email is ", email!)
   print("completion is ", completion!)
}
```

Comment: `email is  nil`
`completion is  nil`, when placed above `Auth.auth().createUser...`

Comment: of course it would be if before createUser - what about after?

Comment: It gives me the same result.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.... (I know, that is why you asked the question!)  You said "I'm getting the .emailAlreadyInUse error" - is that in the print(error!) line? That should be a code.... - What do you get if adding "print("errCode from createUser is ", errCode)" after "if let errCode...." line? (just trying to take it down to a step-by-step to find this)  Lastly (for now), you should use 'tips on where you are' when doing a 'print' (see my print examples) - you show three 'print' statements in your code, but none has a 'tip' - so it may be the thing you see is not from where you think.

Comment: That error is from within the `switch` statement: `case .emailAlreadyInUse:`. So it's creating an account then instead of using that new account to go ahead and sign in, it seems to run the createUser block again for some reason.

EDIT: Ha, I figured out what's wrong. When I press the register button it registers the user, but doesn't log them in/perform the segue. So when I press it again it's giving me that error.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my issue. The `.save()` function had a `.saveProfileImage()` embedded in it, which ran when a user registered. I commented that function out as I implemented the image saving a different way. However, in that `.saveProfileImage()` was a `completion(error)` which was also commented out, therefore making `func save(completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {}` not work. I just turned it into `func save()` to fix it.

Here's the old `save()` function:

```
func save(completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {

        let ref = AppDatabaseReference.users(uid: uid).reference()
        ref.setValue(toDictionary())

        //save the user's profile image
        if let profileImage = self.profileImage {
            let firImage = FirebaseImage(image: profileImage)
            firImage.saveProfileImage(uid, { (error) in
                //called when profile image is successfully uploaded
                completion(error)
            })
        }
    }
```

`.saveProfileImage()`:

```
func saveProfileImage(_ userUID: String, _ completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {

        let resizedImage = image.resize()
        if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(resizedImage, 0.9) {
            //get the reference
            ref = AppStorageReference.profileImages.reference().child(userUID)
            downloadURLString = ref.description

            //save data to reference
            ref.putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metaData, error) in
                completion(error)
            })
        }

    }
```

and what saved the user after registration:

```
else if let user = user {

                    let username = self.firstNameTextField.text!
                    let name = self.firstNameTextField.text!
                    let email = self.emailTextField.text!
                    let profileImage = ""
                    let password = self.passwordTextField.text!

                    let newUser = User(uid: user.uid, username: username, name: name, profileImage: profileImage, email: email, userCoins: 0, questsComplete: 0, rewardsRedeemed: 0, streak: 0, isSubscribed: false)

                    newUser.save(completion: { (error) in
                        if error != nil {
                            print(error!)
                        } else {
                            //successfully initialised
                            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
                                if error != nil {
                                    print(error!)
                                } else {
                                    print("segue to perform")
                                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "registerToMainMap", sender: self)
                                }
                            })

                        }
                    })

                }
```

**New** `save()`:

```
func save() {
  let ref = AppDatabaseReference.users(uid: uid).reference()
  ref.setValue(toDictionary())
}
```

Saving the user:

```
else if let user = user {

                    let username = self.firstNameTextField.text!
                    let name = self.firstNameTextField.text!
                    let email = self.emailTextField.text!
                    let profileImage = ""
                    let password = self.passwordTextField.text!

                    let newUser = User(uid: user.uid, username: username, name: name, profileImage: profileImage, email: email, userCoins: 0, questsComplete: 0, rewardsRedeemed: 0, streak: 0, isSubscribed: false)

                    newUser.save()
                    //successfully initialised
                    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
                        if error != nil {
                            print(error!)
                        } else {
                            print("segue to perform")
                            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "registerToMainMap", sender: self)
                        }
                    })

                }
```